# How to check if the URL is an image and detect it's height and width

Tags: jquery, image

I'm working on a banner system and I want to check if the text that the user wrote in the input is an URL of existing image, and then detect the height and width of it. 
Tried this, but it is not working:

```
<div id="image">

</div>
<script>
    function checkimage( me ){
        $("#image").html("<img src=\""+ me +"\" style=\"display: none;\" onload=\"imageready(\""+me+"\")\" />");
    }
    function imageready( me ){
        var ih = $("#image > img").height();
        var iw = $("#image > img").width();
        if(ih == 90 && iw == 728){
            var style = "Leaderboard";
            image.css({"border":"none", "height":"18px", "width":"326px", "outline-color":"#8F8F8F"}); 
        }else if(ih == 600 && iw == 160){
            var style = "wideskyscraper";
            image.css({"border":"none", "height":"18px", "width":"326px", "outline-color":"#8F8F8F"}); 
        }else{
            allow = false;
            image.css({"border":"1px solid #F00", "height":"16px", "width":"324px", "outline-color":"#F00"});
        }
    }
</script>
```

I saw a lot of questions about is, and none of them helped.

Comment: change misspelled heigh() to height().

Comment: @durgesh.patle thanks, but it is not the only problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to call two method, you can do it with jQuery very easily:

**`HTML Code:`**

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

**`jQuery Code:`**

```
function IsValidImageUrl(urlOfImage) {
    $('#image').html($("<img>", {
            src : urlOfImage,
            error : function () {
                // if url is not image
                alert(urlOfImage + ': ' + false);
            },
            load : function () {
                alert(urlOfImage + ': ' + true);
                // get url image height and width
                console.log(this.width + ' x ' + this.height);
                var ih = this.height;
                var iw = this.width;
                if (ih == 90 && iw == 728) {
                    var style = "Leaderboard";
                    $(this).css({
                        "border" : "none",
                        "height" : "18px",
                        "width" : "326px",
                        "outline-color" : "#8F8F8F"
                    });
                } else if (ih == 600 && iw == 160) {
                    var style = "wideskyscraper";
                    $(this).css({
                        "border" : "none",
                        "height" : "18px",
                        "width" : "326px",
                        "outline-color" : "#8F8F8F"
                    });
                } else {
                    allow = false;
                    $(this).css({
                        "border" : "1px solid #F00",
                        "height" : "16px",
                        "width" : "324px",
                        "outline-color" : "#F00"
                    });
                }
            }
        }))
}
// How to use
IsValidImageUrl("https://www.google.com/logos/2012/hertz-2011-hp.gif");
//IsValidImageUrl("http://google.com");a
```

Fiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/7tbZq/):

Comment: I add to the HTML `style:"display:none;"`, and it doesn't work. I also have problem with the `img` tag on my google chrome, only on my computer and in my website, so the error is because the display none or it is only in my computer? (If you can, please chack if it works for you: http://www.web-gen.net/ad/. here is a banner image that the system should accept: http://www.hamovhotov.com/advertisement/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/160x600ad.gif)

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was indeed in my computer only. Thank you very much `:)`

Comment: Hi @VladGincher, You are most welcome. http://www.web-gen.net/ad/ is working for me in FF and Chrome. I didn't find any error, after form submitting nothing happens for me.

Comment: I know, I didn't added the AJAX for the submitting yet. Thank you very mach :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following;

```
$('<img/>').attr('src','http://explainafide.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/jquery-logo.png').load(function(){ 
    alert("Height: " + $(this).height() + ", Width:" + $(this).width()); 
}).appendTo("#image_hidden");
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/LmpB6/**

**Alternative way:**

You can make a service for getting img size;

**imgsize.php**

```
<?php
$img = $_GET["img"];

$size = getimagesize($img);

echo json_encode(array("width"=>$size[0], "height"=>$size[1]));

?>
```

and in your js;

```
$.getJSON("imgsize.php?img=" + your_image_href, function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting into DOM to detect image is loaded, you could use image object:

```
function checkimage(me) {
     var img = new Image();  
     img.onload = function () {
         imageready(me);
     }
     img.src = me;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go  with answer given by @bingjie2680)
And this is  your modified code-

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="image">

 </div>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     checkimage("http://www.bhmpics.com/walls/best_wallpapers_for_laptop-wide.jpg"); 
   });

   function checkimage( me ){
         $("#image").html("<img src=\""+ me +"\" style=\"display: none;\" onload=\"imageready(this)\" />");
}
function imageready( me ){

    var ih = $(me).height();
    var iw = $(me).width();
alert("height="+ih+" and width="+iw);
    if(ih == 90 && iw == 728){
        var style = "Leaderboard";
        $('#image').css({"border":"none", "height":"18px", "width":"326px", "outline-color":"#8F8F8F"}); 
    }else if(ih == 600 && iw == 160){
        var style = "wideskyscraper";
        $('#image').css({"border":"none", "height":"18px", "width":"326px", "outline-color":"#8F8F8F"}); 
    }else{
        allow = false;
        $('#image').css({"border":"1px solid #F00", "height":"16px", "width":"324px", "outline-color":"#F00"});
    }
}
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```